# AlarmManager gets canceled after a while

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am writing my first app and I'm trying to fire a notification at a specific time every day that reports some information.
For starter, I created the following class that I use to restart the alarms after a reboot and to start the alarms from the main app (this to have just one piece of code to reuse).

```
public class SetAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startReminderService(context);
    }

    public void checkServiceRunning(Context context) {
        Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        reminderIntent.setAction("MyReminder");
        // I check if a reminder is already active
        boolean reminderActive = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REMINDER_SERVICE,
                reminderIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        Log.d("test", "The reminder is active?" + reminderActive);
        if (!reminderActive) {
            startReminderService(context);
        }
    }

    public void startReminderService(Context context) {
        Calendar serviceNotificationTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        serviceNotificationTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        serviceNotificationTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        serviceNotificationTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        reminderIntent.setAction("MyReminder");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            REMINDER_SERVICE,
            reminderIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager serviceAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        serviceAlarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            serviceNotificationTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            Log.d("test", "Background service set up and running.");
        } else {
            Log.d("test", "Failed to set up background service!");
        }
    }
}
```

After that I updated the manifest with the following lines:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.services.SetAlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.services.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MyReminder" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So far, everything goes right. When the phone reboots, the reminder is correctly restarted and (if the reminder time is in the past) it fires immediately.

The AlarmReceiver class is the following:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.ctx = context;
        remindStuff();
    }

    private void remindStuff() {
        ....
        some code
        ....

        // I check if the alarm is still on (probably awful, since it just fired)
        SetAlarmReceiver setAlarmReceiver = new SetAlarmReceiver();
        setAlarmReceiver.checkServiceRunning(ctx);
    }
}
```

I use the same approach to check if the alarm is on from the main activity:

```
private void checkServicesRunning() {
    SetAlarmReceiver setAlarmReceiver = new SetAlarmReceiver();
    setAlarmReceiver.checkServiceRunning(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Everything looks correct to me, I've tried any solution I found, reading tons of questions like mine on StackOverflow but I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
The alarm fires correctly right after BOOT_COMPLETED is triggered by the system and it fires correctly when I just enabled the alarm (only if the notification time is in the past - f.e. when it's 10pm and the alarm must fire at 9am).
When the checkServiceRunning method runs, it tells me that the alarm is already enabled (returning true in the Logcat) but when I close the app and I re-run it after a while, the alarm looks like it's been canceled and it's being recreated by the app.

Any hint?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I tried the command 'adb shell dumpsys alarm' and it actually shows my alarm running correctly so, at this point, I think the issue is something else but I cannot understand what...